# How to disable button when having 'some' text in a text field and re enabled them when that text disappears in the text field

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, jtextfield

The situation is that the JButton1 corresponds to JLabel1, JButton2 to JLabel2 and so on. However I want to disable the JButton# when the value of Jlabel returns on the TextField and reenable them when it is gone.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class qwerty {

ArrayList<JTextField> tfs = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
ArrayList<JButton> bts = new ArrayList<JButton>();


int counter = 0;
String answer;
JLabel j1 = new JLabel("Mark");
JLabel j2 = new JLabel("Joe");
JLabel j3 = new JLabel("John");
JLabel j4 = new JLabel("Ray");

public static void main(String[] args) {
   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new qwerty();
        }
    });
}
 public qwerty() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    // Add new buttons to bts
    bts.add(new JButton("Button1"));
    bts.add(new JButton("Button2"));
    bts.add(new JButton("Button3"));
    bts.add(new JButton("Button4"));

   // Add new textfields to tfs
   tfs.add(new JTextField());
   tfs.add(new JTextField());
   tfs.add(new JTextField());



   j1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
   j2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
   j3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
   j4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));


    for (JButton b : bts) {
        b.addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener());
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        frame.getContentPane().add(b);
    }

        frame.getContentPane().add(j1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(j2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(j3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(j4);



    for (JTextField tf : tfs) {
        tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        tf.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tf);
    }


    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (counter >= tfs.size()) {
            counter = 0;
        }

        String a = ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).getText();
        if (a == "Button1"){
        tfs.get(counter).setText(j1.getText());
        }   

        if (a == "Button2"){
        tfs.get(counter).setText(j2.getText());
        }

        if (a == "Button3"){
        tfs.get(counter).setText(j3.getText());
        } 

        if (a == "Button4"){
        tfs.get(counter).setText(j4.getText());
        } 

        counter++;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html

I think this class does what you want.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider sort of however i will i able put this to multiple field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class qwerty implements DocumentListener{

ArrayList<JTextField> tfs = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
ArrayList<JButton> bts = new ArrayList<JButton>();


int counter = 0;
String answer;
JLabel j1 = new JLabel("Mark");
JLabel j2 = new JLabel("Joe");
JLabel j3 = new JLabel("John");
JLabel j4 = new JLabel("Ray");

JButton b1 = new JButton("Button1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("Button2");
JButton b3 = new JButton("Button3");
JButton b4 = new JButton("Button4");

public static void main(String[] args) {
   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new qwerty();
        }
    });
}
public qwerty() {

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

// Add new buttons to bts
bts.add(b1);
bts.add(b2);
bts.add(b3);
bts.add(b4);

Add new textfields to tfs
tfs.add(new JTextField());
tfs.add(new JTextField());
tfs.add(new JTextField());



   j1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
   j2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
   j3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
   j4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));


for (JButton b : bts) {
    b.addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener());
    b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
    frame.getContentPane().add(b);
}

    frame.getContentPane().add(j1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(j2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(j3);
    frame.getContentPane().add(j4);



for (JTextField tf : tfs) {
    tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
    tf.setEditable(false);
    tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    frame.getContentPane().add(tf);

}


frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);

}
        public boolean isDataEntered1()
    {

    for (JTextField tf : tfs)
    {

        if ("Mark".equals(tf.getText()))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

    public boolean isDataEntered2()
{

    for (JTextField tf : tfs)
    {

        if ("Joe".equals(tf.getText()))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

     public boolean isDataEntered3()
{

    for (JTextField tf : tfs)
    {

        if ("John".equals(tf.getText()))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

     public boolean isDataEntered4()
{

    for (JTextField tf : tfs)
    {

        if ("Ray".equals(tf.getText()))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}


@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
   checkData();
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    checkData();
}

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

private void checkData()
{
    b1.setEnabled(isDataEntered1());
    b2.setEnabled(isDataEntered2());
    b3.setEnabled(isDataEntered3());
    b4.setEnabled(isDataEntered4());
}

 public class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (counter >= tfs.size()) {
        counter = 0;
    }

    String a = ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).getText();
    if (a == "Button1"){
    tfs.get(counter).setText(j1.getText());
    }   

    if (a == "Button2"){
    tfs.get(counter).setText(j2.getText());
    }

    if (a == "Button3"){
    tfs.get(counter).setText(j3.getText());
    } 

    if (a == "Button4"){
    tfs.get(counter).setText(j4.getText());
    } 

    counter++;
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `DocumentListener` to monitor the change in the text field and then set the state of the button.

Here is some code that allows you to associate 1 (or more) text fields with a button.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DataEntered implements DocumentListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    public DataEntered(JButton button)
    {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void addTextField(JTextField textField)
    {
        textFields.add( textField );
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    }

    public boolean isDataEntered()
    {
        for (JTextField textField : textFields)
        {
            if (textField.getText().trim().length() == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    private void checkData()
    {
        button.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JButton submit = new JButton( "Submit" );
        submit.setEnabled( false );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

        DataEntered de = new DataEntered( submit );
        de.addTextField( textField1 );
        de.addTextField( textField2 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Text must be entered in all text field in order to enable the button.

In your case you have a one-to-one mapping of text field to button, so you only need to enter text in one text field in order to enable the related button.

Comment: I can't seem to work it out using your code. I can't re-enabled the button.

Comment: I figured it out! I used many public boolean isDataEntered() for each of my button!. Thank you.